# Send JWT token with External Data Source for Odata v4 endpoint in header

Tags: authentication, jwt, lightning-connect, externalobjects, odata

I am trying to Authenticate the Calls to My Odatav4 ,
In My Service I have started accepting JWT token in header and it is working if i call the service in postman with JWT token in header,

Now in my salesforce Org i am using this service to get External Objects from other system, i need to send JWT token in header when the Salesforce connect calls my Odata4 endpoint,

Salesforce DOcs are really not that helpful.

Any Suggestions would be of great help.

Thanks
Arjun.M

Comment: Where from/how is Salesforce getting the JWT? and what header is your ODatav4 service expecting to find the JWT in?

Comment: Hi Dan 

Salesforce is not getting JWT , but i have service(Odata) which is expecting JWT token in header,

I have added this service in my External Data Source and to get the data from service currently it is configured asNo Authentication, but i need to Pass JWT header with Named Principles or Per user, anything is fine , but In SF i can see is only SOQL query , and SF Connect changes this Query to Odata URL .

Comment: If you haven't got the JWT, you can't send it. In the implementation I have setup, it uses a named principal on the named credential and is set to send a token in the header. That header is a bearer token obtained from the auth endpoint. The odata service then verifies the bearer token with the auth service (and gets the JWT in response to that check, rather than receiving the JWT from Salesforce)

Comment: @Dan can you share some lights here with examples

Answer (score 0):

Consider your odata service to be the "Resource Server" (RS) and Salesforce to be the "Resource Client" (RC). You will have configured your (Salesforce) auth provider with the details of the "Authorization Server" (AS).

When the named credential is configured with the auth provider, and then the named credential is utilised (either via your own apex code, or via Salesforce internals that are converting the data requests into OData requests against your external data source), Salesforce authenticates with the supplied credentials and (makes a POST) to the AS. In the (successful) response, it gets an access token (AT) (amongst other things).

If you check the option on the named credential to "Generate Authorization Header", that AT retrieved from the AS will be sent as a header with the request.

```
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
```

The RS (your odata service) will receive that that header, and is required to validate the token. (i.e. check that the request is authorised)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296017/how-to-validate-an-oauth-2-0-access-token-for-a-resource-server) addresses the same subject.
One of the answers states:

```
the interface between Resource Server and Authorization Server for token validation was standardized in IETF RFC 7662 in October 2015
```

and links to [this spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662)

Essentially, your odata service will receive a bearer token, and needs to use it to request a JWT from the authorisation server. The JWT will supply the relevant assertions: Issuer, audience etc. that your odata service can check to see if it is happy to serve the response.

Comment: Yes Named Credentials are set up in My ORG and i can see that it is sending Bearer token

Here is an example of bearer token "PAQABAAAAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7Wevr0lE_OqTIEE2rPAmWX7cDsepIPKJkAOgIdCfC2vfbugqbHQYmz9jJDOv8u5ENonq5uC8oUOKs_86DF9fmUYzATM__3hZnQNgqNDBZ58Qp7F5k4QBfAxAdsY"

In my .NetCore Odata 4 controller i need to validate this . as this is not the JWT token how can i even validate this token ?

Sorry for asking these basic question, but i am stuck here in this for long.

Thanks for your help in advance .

Comment: Look at the auth. provider record linked to your named credential. What type is it? OpenId, Microsoft Access Control Services, LinkedIn, Google, Salesforce, GitHub?
What is the authorise endpoint? (don't share the key or secret here). Once you have these, you can lookup the documentation for that auth. provider which should indicate how you verify the bearer token. Typically, this would be a GET on a similar URL to the authorise endpoint which returns the JWT (or some other structure with relevant details)

Comment: Yes its openId connect ,but i dont see any documentation where i can get JWT from above token .

Comment: What is the authorisation endpoint?

Comment: https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize

Comment: The bearer token should be a base64 encoded version of the JWT you are expecting.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/bearer-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/
Read just beyond "Testing the Authentication Server"
The token you supplied in an earlier comment appears to be invalid though, maybe you truncated it? (don't post the full bearer token here), try to decode it through https://jwt.io/

Comment: Token is truncated, but the token is not JWT for sure, if it was JWT it would easy to validate, above comment has first half of the token.

that's why its a puzzle here ..

Comment: And is there a way to get JWT along with named credentials ?

Comment: If you base64 decode the bearer token it should be the JWT.

Comment: When I tried this, I didn't get an Authorization header. I did check the "Generate Authorization Header" option. Is there something else that would cause the Authorization header to not be sent?

Comment: Send access token in header should be checked in Auth Provider , so JWT will be sent across

Comment: Here is the Answer

We need Auth Provider in my case i used Open Id Connect Consumer Key Consumer Secret you can generate new one if you want.

End points Authorize Endpoint URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/appid/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Token Endpoint URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/appid/oauth2/v2.0/token

In Azure APP Add redirect Uri (Once Auth Provider is saved , you will see this in Auth Provider you saved ) <https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/authprovidername> Redirect URIs

Update : External Data Source Scope api://appid/.default

Comment: Created a post for the same for complete implementation
https://medium.com/@shrivatsa.arjun/odata-service-with-netcore-salesforce-connect-c48006702c2e